# Несколько служб в одном exe

Tags: c#, windows-service, service

Существует служба (написанная на C#), под управлением которой трудятся несколько потоков.
Необходимо перенести функционал утилиты (реализованный в отдельном C# приложении) в службу, но плодить службы нет ни какого желания.
В связи с этим...

**Вопрос**: Можно ли объединить в *одном exe* несколько служб, и если да - как их устанавливать ?

**PS**: буду признателен за примеры и полезные ссылки.

Comment: Хорошо, вот я написал несколько классов-служб и классов-установщиков.  
Корректна ли будет такая запись в *Program.cs* :
    
    ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
    ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] { 
        new WindowsService() 
    };
    ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Исполняемый файл может содержать несколько служб, причем для каждой службы в этом файле должен существовать отдельный объект ServiceInstaller. Экземпляр ServiceInstaller регистрирует службу в системе. Кроме того, с каждой службой связывается журнал событий, в который записываются команды службы. Службы, которые должны запускаться, определяются функцией main() исполняемого файла. Текущей рабочей папкой службы является системная папка, но не папка, в которой находится исполняемый файл.

Источник: [материал MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase(v=vs.90).aspx).

Посмотрите вот здесь: [размещение нескольких служб в одном процессе](http://www.itarchive.ru/archives/369).